# Why the mssql object can not be identified?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, azure, mobile, azure-mobile-services

I am getting below error when using mssql object in script as:

```
var mssql =request.services.mssql;
```

Log entry details

ERROR

> Error in script '/api/apitest.js'. TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'mssql' of undefined
>       at exports.get (D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts\api\apitest.js:3:31)
>       [external code]

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the whole code for your script? Where is that line `var mssql = ...`? Inside a GET function? Somewhere else?

Comment: exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var mssql = request.service.mssql;
    var sql = "Select * from item ";
    mssql.query(sql, {
        success: function(results) { 
            console.log(results);
            if(results.length == 1)         
                response.send(200, results);         
        }
    })
};

Comment: Hi,

I think it is not recognizing because runtime needs to be selected as "node.js" but in our case we are not able to find the same option. 

While creating a new mobile service also we get only javascript and .net as beckend. If node.js as runtime needs to be selected then where we can select it?

Please provide your inputs.

Comment: If you select JavaScript, then your runtime is using node.js. How are you calling your API? By sending a GET request to `your-mobile-service.azuremobile.net/api/your-api-name`, or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be a typo: it's `request.service.mssql`, not `request.services.mssql` as you have in your question (there's no **s** at the end of `service`). Try using the appropriate property name and you should be able to get to the `mssql` object.