# SQL query in javascript on Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have followed a tutorial to write a script on Azure for a custom SQL to retrieve some data: 
https://www.tapanila.net/windows-azure-mobile-services-custom-api-for-existing-sql-database/

Im working on a mobile service, and use "Easy API" on Azure.

I get an error when I write this script:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    request.service.mssql.query(
        'select * from varegrupper', {
        success: function(results) {
            response.send(200, results);
        }
    });
};
```

This is my error:

```
{"error":"Cannot read property 'mssql' of undefined"}
```

Any idea what I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a significant difference between Mobile Services (now deprecated) and Mobile Apps. The API you're trying to work with is the Mobile Services API, where you are using Mobile Apps. You can find a sample project with a custom API that executes SQL statements [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/tree/master/samples/custom-api-sql-stmt). You can also find some reference documentation [here](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/module-azure-mobile-apps_src_data_execute.html#~execute).

Comment: You nailed it. Poor official documentation. Thank you!

Comment: The documentation you are using (tapanila.net) is not official.  The official documentation is on azure.com - go to Documentation -> Web & Mobile -> Mobile Apps

Answer (score 1):

Try to directly use `mssql` object in the code, because the objects in the list of the [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554212.aspx) which can be directly used for mobile service javascript backend. More details for `mssql` object, please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554212.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried this. But the Visual Studio online does not know anything about this object it seems. See image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oxjekrhsdz7stjb/mssql.png?dl=0

Comment: Found a similar case here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264430/why-the-mssql-object-can-not-be-identified but no solutions. Maybe I am missing something in the Azure setup?

Comment: @LarsØrjanNese Does it works with ignoring code check? The code of the similar case seems to be from the offical tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-define-custom-api/. I doubt the issue was caused by inputting the incorrect user/password for SQL Azure. Please try to connect the SQL Azure alone before create mobile service instance.

Comment: I get access to the SQL Azure from "everywhere". And my app (iOS) is working like a charm to access the Azure SDK to run simple queries. But to use this api thing seems tricky.